# How do i use functions in loops, or call functions

Tags: javascript

Could anyone help with my home work please? my codes are not running and showing blank page and i think i have errors somewhere. could someone help so can compare my answers? I know this is really easy but am on beginner level, i need genius help!!!

1.Write a function that takes one number and returns the square of that number. Use that function in a for loop to print the square of numbers from 1 to 10 on the page.

2.Write a function that takes 3 numbers and returns the largest of these 3 numbers.
Test the function by calling it and passing 3 numbers to it. The caller should write the return value to the page.

3.Write a function expression for a function that adds two numbers. Call the function before defining it to show that it will cause an error and after defining it to show that it works.
The function should return the result of adding the two numbers that were passed to it.
    The caller should write the result to the page.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please show us your code. Without your code we can't guess where is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple:

```js
function square(n) {
  return n * n;
}

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  document.write(square(i) + "<br>");
}
```

---

```js
function largest(num1, num2, num3) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, [num1, num2, num3]);
}

document.write(largest(5, 6, 100));
```

(This is a more dynamic solution because it can get the largest from any amount of numbers):

```js
function largest(...nums) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, nums);
}

document.write(largest(2, 76, 3, 98, 12, 654));
```

---

```js
//add(2, 3); //Causes error which is why this line is commented out

var add = function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

document.write(add(2, 4));
```

(Again - more versatile solution to add multiple numbers)

```js
function add(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}

document.write(add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```

Comment: could i please know why "in the first solution "you have square(i) inside document.write? i have the same solution but i just used a string message and my page was blank. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: function square(x){
             return x * x;
             }
        for(var x = 1; x <= 10; x++;){
            
        }
        square(x);
        document.write(" the square on numbers 1 to 10 is" + x + "<br>" );

Comment: There, `x` will not be changed because JavaScript is pass-by-value. You would have to do `var y = square(x); document.write("The square of " + x + " is " + y);

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
function calcSquare(number) {
    return number*number;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write(calcSquare(i));
}
```

2.

```
function largestNumber(number1, number2, number3) {
    var largest = number1 > number2 ? number 1 : number2;
    largest = largest > number3 ? largest : number3;
    return largest;
}

document.write(largestNumber(10, 20, 30));
```

3.

```
function addTwoNumbers(number1, number2) {
    return number1+number2;
}

document.write(addTwoNumber(10,5));
```